# Irreducibility of a polynomial given a condition on the sum of its roots

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $F$. Let $K/F$ be an extension that contains all the roots $\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_n$ of $p(x)$. Suppose that the sum of any the roots of $p(x)$ is not in $F$, unless the sum is 0 or the sum includes all the roots.

To prove: $p$ is irreducible over $F$.

Attempt: Suppose $p$ is reducible. Write $p(x) = g(x)h(x)$ where both $g$ and $h$ have degree $< n$. Consider $g$. Then $g$ has at most $n - 1$ roots, so some $\alpha_i$ is not a root of $g$. Then...?

I really don't see how to use the condition on the sums of the roots and how they relate to the (ir)reducibility of $p$.

Hints?

Comment: Hint: for a monic polynomial of degree $n$, the sum of the roots is $\pm$ the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson How to see that? And how to use it once I understand that?

Comment: To see it: try it by hand for $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, say, it should become obvious. To use it: give yourself more time before seeking additional help :).

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Ok, I looked into why the sum of the roots is the coefficient  of $x^{n - 1}$. As for how to proceed, I note that if $p$ is reducible, then $p = gh$ for two polynomials of strictly smaller degree. Then neither can have any linear factors over $F$, because then the sum of the coefficients would be in $F$, a contradiction. But if they don't have any linear factors, where's the contradiction? Say $p$ is of degree 10, and $g$ and $h$ are each of degree 5, but each of those are irreducible. Why can't this happen?

Comment: Why restrict to linear factors of $f$ and $g$? It's fine if they're both degree 5, say, there's no issue.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I don't follow. What is $f$?

Comment: Typo, $g$ and $h$ rather. Say $p=gh$ where $g, h$ were each irreducible over $F$ of degree 5. How do they factor over $K$?

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson All of the roots of $p$ are in $K$, so the roots of $g$ and the roots for $h$ must account for all the roots. Hence they each must factor completely over $K$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112759/discussion-between-joshua-p-swanson-and-junglemath).